# How to do nested templating using Jinja in an Airflow DAG?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa

The following template for bucket_key works and it pulls the output value from task aTestPyOperator:

```py
sensor = S3KeySensor(
        task_id='check_s3_for_file_in_s3',
        bucket_name='my_bucket',
        bucket_key= "{{params.folder}}/{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='aTestPyOperator') }}/",
        params={'folder': 'test'}
    )
```

But what I need to be able to do is pass in the name of the task that it should use.

```py
sensor = S3KeySensor(
        task_id='check_s3_for_file_in_s3',
        bucket_name='my_bucket',
        bucket_key= "{{params.folder}}/{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='{{params.fnName}}') }}/",
        params={'folder': 'test',
                'fnName': 'aTestPyOperator'}
    )
```

The above does not work and the template looks like "test/NONE". I think what its evaluating is ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='{{params.fnName}}') and not ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='aTestPyOperator').

I have also tried it like this (removed the nested braces) and that didn't work either.

```py
bucket_key= "{{params.folder}}/{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='params.fnName') }}/",
```

At the end, what I am trying to do is set the bucket key with the output value from the previous task. Is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the `params` as a variable inside a Jinja template.

```
bucket_key= "{{ params.folder }}/{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=params.fnName) }}/",
```

Even more, you can rewrite your template in that way:

```
bucket_key= "{{ params.folder + '/' + ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=params.fnName) }}/",
```

Comment: I found this also works! bucket_key="parent/{{ params.folder + '/' + ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=params.fnName) }}/"

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following to work, but wondering if there is a way to nest templates as it might look cleaner than having to weed through multiple braces!

Working solution:

```py
folder_name = 'test'
fnName = 'aTestPyOperator'

bucket_key= f"{folder_name}/{{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='{fnName}') }}}}/"
```

The solution relies on string format interpolation, which seems to occur first and then the jinja templating seems to work. By doubling up the curly braces, string interpolation removes them and converts it to:

**"test/{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='aTestPyOperator') }}/"**

and finally jinja does its thing and outputs:

**"test/output_location/"**

assuming that aTestPyOperator returned "output_location"